# How do I say “everything started here”?

Tags: idiom, grammar-choice, english-to-latin-translation

I would like like to translate "everything started here" in Latin. Would *omni coepia hinc* work?

Answer (score 6):

No.

I’m not quite sure how you arrived at your final result; *omnī* is the ablative singular of *omnis, omne*, which doesn’t make much sense if you are trying to convey the word *everything*; *coepia*, well, I’m not really sure if it even exists; and *hinc* means *hence*, *hencforth*, *from here*, etc., not *here*. All together, the phrase you’ve got is completely unintelligible.

Go for this instead:

> *Omnia hīc coepērunt.*

If you want to avoid *potential* ambiguity regarding the subject of *coepērunt*, you can always opt for a passive phrase as well (thanks to [@SamK](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/136/sam-k) for pointing this out to me):

> *Omnia hīc coepta sunt*

You can rearrange the word order in either of these phrases to whatever emphasis or style suits you; they are simply a starting point.

Comment: There's also the option to leave *sunt* out, although it could be read as "all the things that started here".

Answer (score -1):

'Everything' needs a Neuter Plural ending; so, *omnia, omnium,* or *omnibus.*

> *[Omnia](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/vocabulary/phrase/1334/)* =Everything.

*Coepi* is a good word, but it is tricky: it looks like a past tense, and behaves like a past tense, but its meaning is present tense. *Coepi* = I begin.
So an 'extra' past tense has to be added. *Omnia coeperunt* =Everything begins

> *[coeperant](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DC%3Aentry%20group%3D60%3Aentry%3Dcoepio)* =began. Lewis and Short (Tufts) *coepio* section II (But notice the ambiguity mentioned by Sam K in the notes.)

*[Hinc](http://Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DH%3Aentry+group%3D13%3Aentry%3Dhinc)* means 'here.' But I would choose

> *[abhinc](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dabhinc)* =from here.

Next, put the words in Latin order. Usually the verb goes last because that is the most significant position. But if you want to emphasise another word, put that last.

Comment: Where are you getting the statement that *coepi* has present meaning? I don't think that's right.

Comment: Agree with TKR here; *coepī, coepisse, coeptum* is perfect in form and perfect in meaning; *incipiō, incipere, incēpī, inceptum* is used for *to begin* in any of the present system tenses. *hinc* also doesn't mean *here*; it carries the meaning of *from here*, *hence*, *henceforth*, etc. and *abhinc* carries a temporal sense with it, which may or may not be what the OP intended with "here".

Comment: @TKR *Coepio* as the examples show means 'instigate,' in the present. In the L&S examples 'begin' is usually perfect, future-perfect, plu-perfect..

Comment: No, TKR and Ethan Bierlein are correct. The L&S entry simply indicates that although there are present, future, and imperfect forms, these are very rare and primarily preclassical (except the future participle, coepturus); only perfect, future perfect, and pluperfect forms are normally found – and these have perfect, future perfect, and pluperfect meanings. In other words, coepi doesn't work like, e.g., odi, where perfect form = present meaning.